# defining std::istringstream record outside the loop

Tags: c++, stringstream

Im doing a exercise in C++ Primer it says that i need to defined `std::istringstream record;` outside the loop so i do it when i test it the first output was ok but the second , third 
are not it seems its not storing  any values in `info.name` and `word` here's the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

struct PersonInfo {
std::string name;
std::vector <std::string> phones;
};

int main()
{
std::string line, word;
std::vector <PersonInfo> people;
std::istringstream record;

 while (std::getline (std::cin, line)) {
   PersonInfo info;

   record.str(line);

   record >> info.name;

   std::cout << info.name << std::endl;

   while (record >> word) {
         info.phones.push_back (word);
         std::cout << word << std::endl;
   }

   people.push_back (info);

}

for (unsigned i = 0; i != people.size(); ++i) {
     std::cout << people[i].name << " ";
      for (unsigned z = 0; z != people[i].phones.size(); ++z) {
        std::cout << people[i].phones[z] << " ";
      }
      std::cout << std::endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

but when i define `std::istringstream record;` inside the outer loop it seems okay.

Comment: The root cause of this problem is pretty-much *identical* [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31444137/c-reading-a-text-file-with-conditional-statements) (though you wouldn't know it from the title).

Comment: yeah it is thanks either i defined record inside the loop or use record.clear() thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because it reached EOF. Either the source material is wrong, or it says to `record.clear()` to clear error flags and you did not follow the instructions properly.

Comment: heres the exercise problem: The program in this section deﬁned its istringstream object inside the outer while loop. What changes would you need to make if record were deﬁned outside that loop? Rewrite the program, moving the deﬁnition of record outside the while, and see whether you thought of all the changes that are needed.